# Combination of two fields to be unique in Python Eve

Tags: python, eve

In Python Eve framework, is it possible to have a condition which checks combination of two fields to be unique?

For example the below definition restricts only **firstname** and **lastname** to be unique for items in the resource.

```
people = {
    # 'title' tag used in item links.
    'item_title': 'person',
    'schema': {
        'firstname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True,
            'unique': True
        },
        'lastname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True,
            'unique': True
        }
}
```

Instead, is there a way to restrict **firstname** and **lastname** combination to be unique?

Or is there a way to implement a CustomValidator for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want by overloading the `_validate_unique` and implementing custom logic there, taking advantage of `self.document` in order to retrieve the other field value.

However, since `_validate_unique` is called for every unique field, you would end up performing your custom validation twice, once for `firstname` and then for `lastname`. Not really desirable. Of course the wasy way out is setting up `fullname` field, but I guess that's not an option in your case.

Have you considered going for a slighty different design? Something like:

```
{'name': {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe'}}
```

Then all you need is make sure that `name` is required *and* unique:

```
{
    'name': {
        'type':'dict', 
        'required': True, 
        'unique': True,
        'schema': {
            'first': {'type': 'string'},
            'last': {'type': 'string'}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola. Using `self.document` I am querying internally to find if the combination is existing already.  Added a new validator for this.

Comment: I tried using the alternate design for the data, but was not successful in getting the validation to work as intended. @Yogeswaran, could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Nicola and `_validate_unique`.

```
from eve.io.mongo import Validator
from eve.utils import config
from flask import current_app as app

class ExtendedValidator(Validator):
    def _validate_unique_combination(self, unique_combination, field, value):
        """ {'type': 'list'} """
        self._is_combination_unique(unique_combination, field, value, {})


    def _is_combination_unique(self, unique_combination, field, value, query):
        """ Test if the value combination is unique.
        """
        if unique_combination:
            query = {k: self.document[k] for k in unique_combination}
            query[field] = value

            resource_config = config.DOMAIN[self.resource]

            # exclude soft deleted documents if applicable
            if resource_config['soft_delete']:
                query[config.DELETED] = {'$ne': True}

            if self.document_id:
                id_field = resource_config['id_field']
                query[id_field] = {'$ne': self.document_id}

            datasource, _, _, _ = app.data.datasource(self.resource)

            if app.data.driver.db[datasource].find_one(query):
                key_names = ', '.join([k for k in query])
                self._error(field, "value combination of '%s' is not unique" % key_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue is by creating a dynamic field using a combination of functions and lambdas to create a hash that will use
which ever fields you provide

```
def unique_record(fields):
    def is_lambda(field):
        # Test if a variable is a lambda
        return callable(field) and field.__name__ == "<lambda>"

    def default_setter(doc):
        # Generate the composite list
        r = [
            str(field(doc)
                # Check is lambda
                if is_lambda(field)
                # jmespath is not required, but it enables using nested doc values
                else jmespath.search(field, doc))
            for field in fields
        ]

        # Generate MD5 has from composite string (Keep it clean)
        return hashlib.md5(''.join(r).encode()).hexdigest()

    return {
        'type': 'string',
        'unique': True,
        'default_setter': default_setter
    }
```

Practical Implementation

My use case was to create a collection that limits the amount of key value pairs a user can create within the collection

```
domain = {
    'schema': {
        'key': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'maxlength': 25,
            'required': True,
        },
        'value': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minlength': 1,
            'required': True
        },
        'hash': unique_record([
            'key',
            lambda doc: request.USER['_id']
        ]),
        'user': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'default_setter': lambda doc: request.USER['_id']  # User tenant ID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function will receive a list of either string or lambda function for dynamic value setting at request time, in my case the user's "_id"

The function supports the use of JSON query with the JMESPATH package, this isn't mandatory, but leave the door open for nested doc flexibility in other usecases

NOTE: This will only work with values that are set by the USER at request time or injected into the request body using the pre_GET trigger pattern, like the USER object I inject in the pre_GET trigger which represents the USER currently making the request